# Couldn't get cell title from another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**My Situation:** i have a "homeviewcontroller", and here I'm wanting to acces a cell title of a tableview of another view. So the title of the cell apears in the homeviewcontroller when its appear.

So, i have a tableviewcontroller. Then i have my homeviewcontroller with a label what want to change the text to the cell title text.

**PROBLEM:** This is my code but it isnt working, the label apears empty.

Home View Controller Code:

Homeviewcontroller.h

```
...
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *celltitle;
...




 Homeviewcontroller.m

    ...
#import "tableviewcontroller"
    @synthesize celltitle;
    ...
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        Tableviewcontroller *hourscell = [tableviewcontroller alloc];
        diahoy.text = hourscell.daylabel.text;
    }
```

and my tableViewController (where i set the cel) method:
...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Hours Cell";

   CellVC *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CellVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Hours *hour = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.daylabel.text = hour.dayselect;

    return cell;
}
```

I want to make clear that my table is working correct, user can add cells without any problem.

Also, it would be great if you know how to get the titlelabel of a certain cell row.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: But what is the relation between these two view controllers ? and are you creating instance of table view in homeviewController..?

Comment: Theres no relation, they are 2 separate views

Comment: It won't work like that.. .either make homeview controller as a parent class for tableviewcotroller or create an instance of tableviewcontroller in homeViewController...by this you can access any property of tableview.

Comment: Thanks, i dont know much about that but at least i have an starting point. Thanks you very much :)

Comment: There must be some relation. They are both on display at the same time? Home pushes the table into its navigation controller? Something... Also, you can't (or very much shouldn't) just call `alloc` (`[tableviewcontroller alloc]`) on a class and then start using it. Always call some `init` method.

Comment: The views are organized in a tabbar

Answer (score 0):

Think you forgot to initialise your `tableViewController`. You did only allocate it in your HomeViewController.m. And the label should be `cellTitle` instead of `diahoy` I guess:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    Tableviewcontroller *hourscell = [[Tableviewcontroller alloc] init];
    celltitle.text = hourscell.daylabel.text;
}
```